# ssh session as python subprocess takes input but does not print it to stdout

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, popen

I'm trying use python's cmd library to create a shell with limited commands.  One requirement I have is to be able to run a command that executes an existing shell script which opens an ssh session on a remote machine and from there allows the user to interact with the remote shell as if it was a regular ssh session.

Simply using subprocess.Popen('[/path/to/connect.sh]') works well at least as a starting point except for one issue.  You can interact with the remote shell but the input that you type is not shown on stdout...so for example you see the prompt on your stdout but when you type 'ls' you don't see it being typed but when you hit return it works as expected.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to print the input to stdout and still send it along to the remote ssh session.

EDIT:
Actual code without using cmd was just the one line:

ssh_session = subprocess.Popen(['connect.sh'])

it was fired from a do_* method in a class which extended cmd.Cmd.  I think I may end up using paramiko but would still be interested in anyone's input on this.

Comment: could you [create a minimal but complete code example that shows the issue (without `cmd`: only `subprocess` + ssh)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Unrelated: make sure to read [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Comment: Perhaps you should use [Paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko), a native python SSH library for interacting with remote shells.

Comment: I think I'm going to end up using Paramiko.  Thanks for both of your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Unix like system, SSH detects if you are on a terminal or not. When it detects that you are not on a terminal, like when using subprocess, it will not echo the characters typed. Instead you might want to use a pseudo-terminal, see [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), or [pty](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pty.html). This way you can get the output from SSH as if it was running on a true terminal.

Comment: `ssh` inherits whatever the parent Python script uses as a stdin/stdout/stderr. It  looks like the parent script is already run interactively in a terminal.

Comment: That is true. It seem I didn't read the question closely enough, but now I read it again, it seems like he is not redirecting the streams. I was thinking more in the lines of working with streams that support ioctl functions (tty, pty, etc.)